# Laravel Google callback url is giving error ("Not found")

Tags: php, laravel, google-signin, laravel-socialite

I am working on login with social account and currently I am testing with Google account. I used Laravel Socialite and read documentation and did everything.  I share my code below, anyone have an idea what I did wrong?

```
<?php
  
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
  
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Socialite;
use Auth;
use Exception;
use App\User;
  
class GoogleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function redirectToGoogle()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }
      
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handleGoogleCallback()
    {
        try {
    
            $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
     
            $finduser = User::where('google_id', $user->id)->first();
     
            if($finduser){
     
                Auth::login($finduser);
    
                return redirect('/home');
     
            }else{
                $newUser = User::create([
                    'name' => $user->name,
                    'email' => $user->email,
                    'google_id'=> $user->id,
                    'password' => encrypt('123456dummy')
                ]);
    
                Auth::login($newUser);
     
                return redirect('/home');
            }
    
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            dd($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**My Google Callback Url**

```
http://localhost:81/auth/google/callback?state=YMuSrsU6925bkwXG59tzHz4Ru8J2VlmOxiG9w5NS&code=4%2F0AY0e-g5f17C96cQZ0CSqtRIOUlq3RcpPj5Y1yp_0ibvDxi_U4S1WOU2QIT_0j7QlfUcabA&scope=email+profile+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&authuser=0&prompt=consent#
```

**Error**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNyd6.png

**Note:** All my routes are correct.

Comment: Did you enter the correct port? It Usually looks like this `http://localhost:8000` and which laravel version do you use?

Comment: Which Laravel version do you use? Also, what's your route? 404 means that your Laravel project does not recognize this route as a registered route

Comment: @GeorgeG this was helpful I kept having this issue and realized in my `web.php` I named the route `login/provider/callback` but in my .env I was trying to use `auth/provider.callback`. Good to double check that.

Answer (score 2):

Check your google Authorized redirect URIs.[image]