# Google callback url returns page not found in Laravel Socialite

Tags: php, laravel

I am building login with google in my web application and I am using a library called sociallite. There I am getting error when google callback url is called from the response.
It is working fine in localhost but not working on live server.
For reference you can see this [Site](http://internaka.com/xnews/public/). Here only I am getting the error.

**LoginController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    // Google login
    public function redirectToGoogle()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }

    // Google callback
    public function handleGoogleCallback()
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();

        $this->_registerOrLoginUser($user);

        // Return home after login
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

    protected function _registerOrLoginUser($data)
    {
        $user = User::where('email', '=', $data->email)->first();
        if (!$user) {
            $user = new User();
            $user->name = $data->name;
            $user->email = $data->email;
            $user->provider_id = $data->id;
            $user->avatar = $data->avatar;
            $user->save();
        }

        Auth::login($user);
    }
}
```

**Routes (routes/web.php)**

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::post('/topic/add', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'addTopic'])->name('topic.add');

// Google login
Route::get('/login/google', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class, 'redirectToGoogle'])->name('login.google');
Route::get('/login/google/callback', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class, 'handleGoogleCallback']);
```

**config/services.php**  <-edit

```
'google' => [
        'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => 'http://localhost/cnews/public/login/google/callback',
    ],
```

**Google console uris in developer console.**

URIs*

1. http://localhost
2. http://internaka.com

Authorized redirect URIs

1. http://localhost/cnews/public/login/google/callback
2. http://internaka.com/xnews/public/login/google/callback

I have gone through many answer but nothing seems to work some of them are
[Code for Facebook and Google Login not working on live server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61522892/code-for-facebook-and-google-login-not-working-on-live-server) 
[Laravel Google callback url is giving error ("Not found")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64919035/laravel-google-callback-url-is-giving-error-not-found)

Comment: check your google Authorized redirect URIs